# Why do we say there is "something at hand" or "there is something a foot"?

Tags: american-english, figures-of-speech

I'm curious about the interpretation of the phrases when used to describe something mysterious or ominous implied in the context, as a figure of speech, not literally, particularly in literature? More specifically how did we get from the literal to the mysterious figurative?

Comment: I'm not aware that _at hand_ does imply any mystery; it just means that something is nearby, within reach of the hand, or coming very soon.

Comment: Only a suggestion, but perhaps a connotation many people have when they hear 'afoot' is Conan Doyle's famous works. Sherlock Holmes used the term, and one always expected a fight against some hidden evil. I don't know if Conan Doyle started this trend, but he certainly popularised it.

Answer (score 6):

Note that the word is "*[afoot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/afoot)*". It means that something is in motion or in action.

"*[At hand](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at_hand)*" means something is within reach or close-by.

There is nothing mysterious or ominous about the words themselves. It's more likely that the "*something*" adds the mystery. An unknown thing happening can be ominous and threatening but that is mostly because of the lack of information and the context that these phrases are used in (Sherlock Holmes comes to mind).

Answer (score 4):

"Afoot" has gone from the literal meaning of "on foot" to often being used to refer to plans or schemes (often evil in nature) which are in motion but of which one has no knowledge. It doesn't necessarily have this negative sense, but it often does.

[Etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=afoot) informs us that the origin is "on foot", and hence "in motion". It suggests the first metaphorical sense is in Shakespeare:

> Now let it work. Mischief, thou art afoot,
> Take thou what course thou wilt!

([Julius Caesar](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/julius_caesar/full.html), act 3 scene 2, c. 1600)

This has influenced later usage. [Collins COBUILD](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/afoot) says of "afoot":

> If you say that a plan or scheme is afoot, it is already happening or being planned, but you do not know much about it.

They give the example:

> Everybody knew that something awful was afoot.

Hence, afoot is often used to refer to bad things, influenced by Shakespeare, and according to COBUILD has the connotation of things in motion that we are unaware of the details of. But it doesn't necessarily have negative connotations: with some subjects like "plans", "schemes", etc, it suggests dark motives, but in other contexts it is neutral.

(I'd guess that it is seldom used today to mean literally "on foot", and when it is used, it has an old-fashioned feel, although [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/afoot) says this sense is more common in North America and I am in the UK.)